# Error is Trying to get property 'id' of non-object, but seems object has

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PHP for 1st time.
I am just trying to fetch data from database. Here is my code -

```
        try{
            ///try to connect with database
            $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=try", "root", "abcdef12");
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo "error";
        }
        $mysqlcode="SELECT * FROM users";
        $ret=$conn->query($mysqlcode);
        foreach($ret as $ret1)
        print $ret1->id;
```

in the browser,
showing this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/secAsite/verifylogin.php on line 44

In the users table, I have 4 data.
In here, why $ret seems non object. I can't find anything wrong. How to fetch data. Or debug the object.

Comment: Have you tried `print $ret1['id']`.  If you get errors like this the try `var_cump($ret1);` to see what the data actually contains (and it's type).

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code. Everything is fine. Just do this.

```
         foreach($ret as $ret1)
            print $ret1['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting data because you are not fetching it..
you have to fetch the data before print it
updated code

```
$mysqlcode = "SELECT * FROM users";
$ret = $conn->query($mysqlcode);

if ($ret->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $ret->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $ret["id"] . "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

that'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to use Object Oriented PHP, is much easier to understand Procedural. Take a look at the code below.

First, connect to database:

```
<?php   
//Store log in info into variables
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $serveruser = 'youruser';
    $serverpassword = 'yourpassword';
    $serverdatabase = 'yourdatabase';

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect( $servername, $serveruser, $serverpassword, $serverdatabase );

    if ( !$conn ) {echo "Connection Fail" . mysqli_connect_error();}
    //else {echo "Connected to database $serverdatabase";}
?>
```

Then, call the information from your `database` and your `table` and store it into an associative array `$data`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASOCC);
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Now you can use the array to print the results with `print_r`

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';}
```

Now you are ready to use `foreach` depending on your table columns,for example if you have ID column then

```
<?php foreach ($data as $value){
echo $value['id]."<br>";
} ?>
```

It will print out all the IDs. Hope this helps.